# Armor for an Age of Sail campaign

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, armor

I am looking to make a campaign set in a world that's technologically and culturally similar to Earth during the Age of Sail (more specifically, think of a a world set in the mid to late 1700's). I want there to be similar uniforms to those times, but I am having trouble a good variety of armor that would be fitting with the setting.

The pirate garb would pretty obviously be a fitting choice, but I would like to give the players a variety of armor to choose from so they can play however they want.

What 5e armor options are there for PCs that fit a semi-historically accurate Age of Sail game?

Comment: I think the way the last sentence was worded triggered people's "looking for a brainstorm" close votes, I have reworded and think this is answerable from a Good Subjective perspective.

Comment: @mxyzplk Thank you for editing my question, sorry if I worded it poorly.

Comment: No problem, the Stack is sensitive to questions that don't seem like they have criteria for a "best answer" and instead just want a list of ideas, because that's not what our format's for.  So in general just stating your problem and what you'd find good about a solution is effective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia Body Armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_armor) states that

> Gunpowder era: French cuirassier of the 19th century (Drawing made by Édouard Detaille, 1885). As gunpowder weapons improved, it became cheaper and more effective to have groups of unarmored men with early guns than to have expensive knights, which caused armor to be largely discarded. Cavalry units continued to use armor for longer. Example include the German Reiter, Polish heavy hussars and the back and breast worn by heavy cavalry units during the Napoleonic wars.

Check also [Wikipedia 18th-century weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:18th-century_weapons) for what weapons you can use (there's rules for Firearms in the DMG).

Comment: So I should be trying to avoid armor that would be heavy? Like should I focus more on light armor that gives dex bonus?

Comment: @Smeef This means you're looking at padded armor in the form of winter coats, and breastplates for the people who think they may actually get within melee distance. Everything else would be totally out-of-date, because it was "better" during this time to keep mobile.

Comment: @PipperChip okay, sounds good. Thanks for the help.